# How does the subjunctive "under' + 'join'?

Tags: etymology

> [[Etymonline:]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=subjunctive&searchmode=none) ... from ***sub* "under"** (see [sub-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sub-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***iungere* "to join"** (see [jugular](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jugular&allowed_in_frame=0)). ...
>
> [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/192731?redirectedFrom=subjunctive) ... The subjunctive mood was so called because it was regarded as `specially appropriate to` **‘subjoined’** or subordinate clauses.  ...

1. I don't understand OED's use of [scare quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) around **subjoined** confuse me. How can a clause be **‘subjoined’**?
2. What does  ***"under" + "to join"** a clause mean?
3. Why was the subjunctive mood `specially appropriate to` them?   I read [this Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/906) post.

Answer (score 2):

Like many Latin grammatical terms, *subjunctive* is a calque from Greek. The Greek term is ὑποτακτικόν *hupotaktikon*, from ὑπο- *hupo-* "under" and the root of τάττω *tattō* "to arrange, place in a specified position". "To arrange under" can mean to subordinate syntactically; the mood was given this name because in Greek, subjunctive forms almost always appear in subordinate clauses. Roman grammarians basically just translated the term into Latin, but used *iungō* presumably because they thought of subordinate clauses as being "joined" to the main clause but on a lower syntactic level ("under").